# Sound doesnt play when object collides with collider/ How to play sound and change scene at the same time - unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello i want sound to play when gameobject collides with collider. I checked Unity documentation for this and i don't seem to understand why this is not working. I have audiosource applied to collider.

```c#
public AudioClip impact;
private AudioSource audioSource;

void Start(){
    audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll){
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
        audioSource.PlayOneShot (impact);
        Application.LoadLevel ("win");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I was trying to load a new level and playing sound at the same time so i just had to add some time seperating with co- routine. now my script looks like this and works. Hope i help someone out.

```c#
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll){
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Enemy") {
        GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();
        StartCoroutine (MyLoadLevel(0.5f , 1));
    }
}

IEnumerator MyLoadLevel(float delay, int level)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
    Application.LoadLevel("win");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in start function because 's'of start is capital

Replace this

**void start()**

with

**void Start()**

This will fix null reference exception

Comment: Honestly, this should have been a comment unless there are other problems in the question.